# To import a PostgreSQL database using the psql

Tags: shell, psql, postgresql-9.5

I'm getting an error after making changes in the `postgresql.conf`

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "IP" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Can someone help me around this?

Comment: How is the server configured in the `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: changed the listen addresses to localhost from '*'